# Converting $matches to PSCustomObject

Tags: regex, powershell

I had created this function to attempt to break strings into groups of tokens that can be made into PowerShell object. This is what I have so far. If I use the code outside of the function I get the desired result but if I attempt to use it within the function I get nothing. I believe the output is disappearing. I know I am not using the right terminology to describe what is happening. Any assistance would be appreciated.

```
Function Convert-MatchToPSCustomObject
{
  <#
  .SYNOPSIS
    Converts $matches to PSCustomObject

  .DESCRIPTION
    Takes an input string and converts it to PSCustomObject

  .PARAMETER Pattern
      Mandatory. Pattern which to match within the string

  .PARAMETER String
      Mandatory. Input String

  .EXAMPLE
    Convert-MatchToPSCustomObject -Pattern '(?<descriptor>^\b[A-Z]{2})(?>[=])(?<value>[\w \.\-]+\b$)' -String 'CN=Only Da Best'

  .LINK
    https://regex101.com/r/1hYb2J/1/

  .LINK
    https://vexx32.github.io/2018/11/08/Named-Regex-Matches-PSCustomObject/

  .NOTES
    Version: 1.0
    Author: Kino Mondesir
  #>
  [cmdletbinding()]
  param
  (
    [Parameter(HelpMessage="Pattern to match", Position=0, Mandatory=$false, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
    [ValidateNotNullorEmpty()]
    [string]$pattern = '(?<descriptor>^\b[A-Z]{2})(?>[=])(?<value>[\w \.\-]+\b$)',

    [Parameter(HelpMessage="Input string", Position=1, Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
    [ValidateNotNullorEmpty()]
    [string]$string
  )
  Try
  {
    return $string -split ',' | ForEach-Object {
      if ($PSItem -match $pattern)
      {
        $Matches.Remove(0)
        [PSCustomObject]$Matches
      }
      else
      {
        Throw "No matching items found!"
      }
    }
  } 
  Catch
  {
    $exception = $_.Exception
    Write-Error $exception.Message
    return -1
  }
}
```

Comment: "if I attempt to use it within the function I get nothing" - please show us the exact code with which you call/invoke the function - the example in the help description works just fine

Comment: If you troubleshooting code, I would recommend to remove the `Try`/`Catch` statements (unless that is related to the question)

Comment: Not quite sure I understand what the issue is but a few things to note, `return` after `$string` seems out of place there. Personally I would change `[string]$pattern` for `[regex]$pattern`, then you can simply use `$pattern.Matches($string)`. Try this outside the function, I think you will find this easier to use :)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The input string is a "CN=Dog,OU=Cat,DN=Mouse". I am expecting the function to take the input string and first split by comma and then split by tokens. I hope I am using the correct terminology. Kinda like how Powershell treats CSV files. Allowing you to work with them as individual items.